# JQuery look up ul with class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing

I would like to add some animations on my menu bar, the code is as follows

html

```
<ul class="my_menu">
    <li class="home">
        <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">The front page</p>
    </li>
    <li class="about">
        <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
        <p class="subtext">More info</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

easing:
http://buildinternet.com/live/smoothmenu/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.my_menu> li").mouseover(function(){
        alert('hi');
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'150px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
    });

    $("ul.my_menu > li").mouseout(function(){
        alert('bye');
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'50px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
    }); 
});
```

Finally, the "hi" and "bye" cannot be displayed. Is there a problem in my code? Thanks in advance.

**Edited: changed am_menu -> my_menu**

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your selector by ul.my_menu?

```
$("ul.my_menu > li")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am sorry because I copied the code from different backup, I am sure there is no naming mistake, thanks.

Comment: Then what isn't working for you? Here is a working fiddle with exactly your code - http://jsfiddle.net/A3vvH/ ??

Answer (score 0):

I can't find  a class `.am_menu` in your html . I think it should be replaced with `ul.my_menu` .

Bug :

```
`$("ul.am_menu > li").mouseover(function(){`  //No class .
```

Fix :

```
`$("ul.my_menu > li").mouseover(function(){`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am sorry because I copied the code from different backup, I am sure there is no naming mistake, thanks.